# how can i left out some tastypie modelresource fields when request for a list of objects

Tags: tastypie

i m a newbie to django, python and tastypie. i creating an API in which i have many resources and each resource has some other related resource.i wanted to get the related objects also when i call for a specific resource. for this In tastypie modelresources i have connected all the resource using ToOneField and ToManyField using _set and lambda function. But now the problem is that if i call the top parent resource list it fetches the complete database and returns it as the response. for example i have a topic resource, a questionresource and answerresource, where question is related to topic and answers is related to question. if i request for the available topic instances it returns all the topics, all the questions related to each topic and all the answers related to each question. what i want to do that if if i send a request for a single resource or for detail view then it should returns the related objects. for list method it should only returns the objects of that particular modelresource ....

tell me eguys how can i do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want using the [`use_in`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#use-in) parameter of the Api fields. It would look like:

```
related_fiedl1 = ToOneField(..., use_in='detail')
related_fiedl2 = ToManyField(..., use_in='detail')
```

You can use it in more complex scenarios by passing a callable (for example to show a field if a parameter is present in the request).

Another thing that's not exactly what you are asking for, but maybe more consistent, is using the [`full_list`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#full-list) and [`full_detail`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#full-detail) parameters, so the relation fields will show a resource url in the list, and the full resource representation in the detail.

Comment: Hey Facundo Olano, can u please give me an example how can i use use_in in my resource. I tried it but it doesn't work for me or i couldn't understand how can i use it in the right way to achieve my goal

Comment: I edited my answer. I'm so used to pass a callable to use_in that I forgot that you can simply pass 'detail' or 'list' to use that field only in those cases.